# How to resize icon inside fab button

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have a fab button that I would like to make smaller.  I am using `fabCustomSize` to achieve this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:fabCustomSize="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />
```

However, I really want the icon to smaller than `24dp` as my button is `24dp`.

I do realize that an easy answer probably adds a smaller icon to my app, however, I already have the `24dp` icon, is there a way to make `24dp` icon smaller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use `app:maxImageSize="your_image_max_size"`

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks!  app:fabCustomSize will set button size and app:maxImageSize will adjust the icon size.